# Android Studio: import project from Gradle

Tags: macos, gradle, android-studio

I want to import my android project (created with Android Studio there are 4 months ago) to my new laptop with Android Studio. So when I select the folder where my project is, a pop-up appears "Import project from Gradle" with different options; by default "Use local gradle distribution" is selected.

But I don't know how to get the Gradle home path on my laptop.

Env:

- MacOSx
- Android Studio v0.8.6 (beta)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do you have gradle installed? If not, following [this](http://blog.diniscruz.com/2013/12/installing-gradle-on-osx.html) guide will help.

Ideally you don't want to select the "Import project from Gradle" option though - you should be using the gradle wrapper created with the project. If there is no gradle wrapper, create a new project and copy the gradle wrapper across.

The gradle wrapper will download the correct gradle version for the project, and avoids the need to have gradle installed locally.

Comment: Thank you! You're right, I did "Open..." instead "Import Project..." from Android Studio. Perfect Athor :)

Answer (score 52):

`Import` project instead of `Open` project

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: As simple as that. "Open existing project" messed me up a lot, while "Import non-Android Studio project" did it right. A bit confusing because it actually is an Android Studio project

Comment: @voghDev Had the same confusion when I opened a gradle supported project on a freshly installed Android Studio. Used "Import non-Android Studio project" and Android Studio automatically downloaded the gradle plugin and setup everything properly.

Comment: yeah @RohanKandwal I guess a lot of developers are falling on that obstacle also. It is good to let everyone know about it ;-)

Comment: This will work for you. You should not import a gradle project but a non-android studio project.

Comment: Its changed in latest Android Studio option to 'Import Eclipse SDK, Android Studio, maven etc project;