# Difference between importing by project name or build.gradle file(Android Studio)?

Tags: android, import, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I import an existing Android Studio application, I noticed I could either import by clicking the build.gradle file or the application itself as in the example shown below(either build.gradle or application name, GradeTrackr)

[image]

Both approaches worked fine. Is there a difference between the two approaches that I should worry about? 
I know that build.gradle is a configuration script(define a task and its settings). I found info about importing a non gradle project -https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html saw questions about import failures [Android Studio: import project from Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537126/android-studio-import-project-from-gradle) but nothing about this.

Comment: I am not aware of any difference. There is a big difference between import a project that does not have a `build.gradle` and one that does. But if the project has `build.gradle`, I am not aware that there is a difference between choosing the project directory or choosing `build.gradle` itself.

Comment: yeah thanks I just wanted to make sure.