# project structure file is missing in existing project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I opened existing project in Android Studio.There are some missing files and I am not able to run existing project. Any help is appreciated. There is no project structure file.

Comment: This description is too terse for us to help you. Please provide error, list of files, ... every information useful to help you.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you opened the project. Typically, I would open it by selecting the build gradle project.
Check out: [Android Studio: import project from Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537126/android-studio-import-project-from-gradle)

If this does not help it may be helpful to let us know what files are missing exactly. A copy/paste or screenshot of the your logs may be useful.